# R concatenate differently stylized characters

Tags: r, string, styles, concatenation

I'd like to name my plot such as "**Plot 1** *(p=0.05)*".
Please note that the title is **bolded** and p value is *italicized*.

I could do manually after plotting contents and do something like:

```
text(x1, y, "Plot 1", font=2)
text(x2, y, "(p=0.05)", font=3)
```

However, it's cumbersome to compute coordinates so I'd like to do something like:

```
title <- (string concatenation here?)
plot(..., main=title)
```

I failed to find any help on this matter so leave this question here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `?plotmath` expressions to do your formatting rather than the `font=` parameters. For example

```
plot(c(1,3), c(1,3))
text(2,2,expression(bold("Plot 1") ~ (italic("p=.05"))))
```

Results in

[image: bold and italic text]

Note that you can't `paste()` expressions together as easily as you can strings. People often then try to but variables for the parts in quotes but in order to do that, you need to build an expression using `bquote()` or `substitute()`. For example

```
plotname <- "Plot 1"
pvalue <- paste0("p=", formatC(.04944, digits=2, format="f"))
text(2,2,bquote(bold(.(plotname)) ~ (italic(.(pvalue)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very good starting point. Can you give me one more suggestion then how to put the text to the top spot as "main=" function does? Text from "text" function is placed behind the plot layer so even if I set y-coordinate the text is covered with plot box i.e., invisible. :(

Comment: Oh I just simply put your solution after "main=" and it works! :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. Try adding expressions into main=.

like this:

```
x<- seq(6:1)
y<-c(5,3,77,6,5,1)
main="title", sub="subtitle"
plot(x,y, main=expression(paste(bold("Plot1"), italic("(p=0.05)"))))
```

[image]